# Xcode 6 jenkins build error

Tags: utf-8, jenkins, xcode6, cocoapods

After updating my jenkins server xcode version to 6, i got the following error.

```
Pods-Facebook-iOS-SDK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBShareDialogParams.o Facebook-iOS-SDK/src/DeviceAPI/FBShareDialogParams.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
22:35:31.397 [DEBUG] [org.openbakery.CommandRunner] (1 failure)
22:35:31.463 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':build'
22:35:31.463 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :build FAILED
22:35:31.463 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :build (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 37.493 secs.
22:35:31.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1 mins 9.044 secs, idle: 0.01 secs
22:35:31.718 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:35:31.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
22:35:31.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:35:31.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
22:35:31.719 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':build'.
```

Anyone came across such an issue.
Also while building I got the warning ,

```
22:34:27.447 [QUIET] [system.out] [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
22:34:27.447 [QUIET] [system.out] See https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues/26 for
```

Is this causing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. 
I was using Pod file, where facebook SDK's version was 3.12. 
When updated it to ,pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.18.2' it worked fine.